# Is @import really that bad to use for performance if using with LESS?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, less

I am planning on dividing up my LESS CSS into multiple files to modularize my CSS and make it easier to manage and maintain. Ultimately I will be using @import to import all of my modular CSS files into one file that will get enqueued in WordPress.

Is @import a bad idea for performance?

Comment: no, but u have to make sure that make a separate file for importing less css dont add any css or less css to it because if you wrote them into top or middle of import lesscss then bottom imported files will not run properly...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using multiple imports will incurr equivalent number of file requests the browser has to make.

As long as you compile the LESS source into a CSS file and include that CSS file as the stylesheet for your site, performance will not be an issue.

For example when you make a Wordpress theme you can make a folder for your CSS and then compile it using for example [simpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) (if you are on Windows)
Sample template directory structure:

```
-themes/
  -your-theme/
    -less/
      -main.less
      -import.less
      -etc.
    -style.css <- this is the target file you would compile into
    -index.php
    -etc.
```

You can setup the target file to compile into easily. Also, simpLESS will keep the first top comment in the resulting file so that you can put your theme information in it.